# Most purchased iOS apps with number of purchases?

Tags: applications, ios, ios-appstore

Where can I find a list of most purchased iPhone / iPad apps WITH the number of buyers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nowhere, unfortunately, because the information isn't reported anywhere. Individual publishers sometimes announce their sales and/or number of purchases, but it's uncommon and there's no reporting at all from the majority of the most successful publishers.

Comment: mhm ok, anyway you know an esteem ? I'm interested in knowing how much a random app usually sell. Not necessarily a famous one.. just to have an idea

Comment: @Patrick: The general consensus is that only a very small percentage of applications (<10% sticks in my head for some reason) are considered profitable relative to the typical development costs that are typically between $35k-$100k. When divided evenly, apps make approx. $4000 each per Apple's published numbers. But in reality, the majority of the money is being made by the large dev companies (i.e. Electronic Arts) or those being run by former large devs (i.e., Angry Birds). If you want to make solid (consistent) money developing apps your best bet is freelance work, not selling one yourself.

Comment: @Patrick I'd comfortably wager that the average paid app averages less than one dollar per day. As @hotpaw2 notes, only the top single-digit percent bring in enough money to meaningfully affect the finances of the developers. This I know from listening to hundreds of devs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official list (available publicly).

Check the blogs of the various developers of popular apps.  A few developers release this very private financial information.

The typical (median popularity ranking) or random paid app usually sells around 0 units per day.

According to reports from some analytics aggregators, an app has to get somewhere in the top 10% to 20% in popularity rankings to average $10 or more in sales per day.  The apps in the top 2% make most of the money.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't a lot of details around on the web. [Camera+](http://campl.us/) seem to have some fairly detailed sales data on their blog. Have a look [here](http://taptaptap.com/blog/cameraplus-first-month-sales/) and [here](http://taptaptap.com/blog/cameraplus-second-month-sales-the-sophomore-software-slump/).

As the other answers note, it would only be individual developers releasing data rather than Apple. Although Apple does list rankings for apps but not actual figures.